# What's the norm in Bessel's inequality? $2-$norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

What's the norm in Bessel's inequality? $2-$norm / Euclidean?

Particularly, a proof writes

$$\|x\|^2=\|x- \sum_{k=1}^n (x | e_k)e_k\|^2+\| \sum_{k=1}^n (x |e_k)e_k\|^2$$

If this is the Euclidean norm, then this splitting makes sense. If it's not, then I'm not sure how the splitting is motivated.

Comment: Your question really miss context. But Bessel inequality hold in inner product spaces, and the norm is the the one induced by the scalar product.

Comment: @user659895 So $\|x\|=\sqrt{(x|x)}$, so $\|x\|^2=(x|x)$ and then since this is just a real number, then one can write like given? Or does one use property of inner product to split the norm?

Comment: yes exactly....